# Mongoose select specific fields from array elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have this schema

```
{
jedi: [{
       name:String
       lightsaber_color:String
      ]}
}
```

I want to return all and only the names of them.
I tried

```
Jedi.find({})
    .select('jedi.name')
    .exec(function (err, jedi) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("nothing found")
      }
}
```

It returns me nothing, while this code returns me everything.

```
Jedi.find({})
        .select('jedi')
        .exec(function (err, jedi) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("nothing found")
          }
    }
```

I see that jedi is an array so I think that `.select('jedi.name')` may not work for this reason. 
What is the right syntax to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this

```
Jedi.find({}, {'jedi.name':1}, function (err, jedi) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("nothing found")
      }
      else{
        console.log(jedi);
      }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this syntax `{'jedi.name':1}`

Comment: In find query first object for query, second object you can pass whatever fields you want to get in result, hope it will work for you.

Comment: I cannot have it working. Basically it returns me the whole structure, not just the names. What's the meaning of the `1` in that code?

Comment: 1 mean i have to return that field

Comment: Is is possible the problem is that the field is being populated with `.populate('jedi')`? Obv the example above is just trivial.

Comment: We do populate if one collection is related with another collection, so to get another collection data, use populate, according to your question my answer is correct, i think you need to have a look on mongoose doc, it seems that you are new to mongoose.